# import P4API fails on win 64, python 3.5.1

Tags: python, p4python

I'm getting the following error when running import P4:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\P4.py", line 410, in <module>
    import P4API
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

- OS: Win 7 64 bit
- Python: 3.5.1
- P4Python: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/P4Python : p4python-2015.2.1348262-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl (md5)

I looked online but couldn't find something that would help.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I expect that one can locate the DLL involved using e.g. some SysInternals tool.

And then use DependencyWalker to check the dependencies of that DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced a slightly different wording of what might be the same issue.

```
 File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\P4.py", line 413, in <module>
    import P4API
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing P4API: The specified module could not be found.
```

To solve it, make sure you have P4V.exe installed. Installing P4V solved the issue for me on Windows 7 and Windows 11.